# How to get internal value of Dojo DateTextBox widget?

Tags: javascript, date, dojo

I have a `dijit/form/DateTextBox` on a form, from which I need to get the internal hidden value (formatted as yyyy-MM-dd) and add that to the URL for an AJAX request.
How do I do this? Will any single method of `DateTextBox` give me that value?

My HTML for the field is:

```
<input id="ialFromDate">
```

I'm creating the widget with a fixed display format with this javascript:

```
var fDate1=new DateTextBox({constraints:{datePattern:'dd/MM/yyyy'}},'ialFromDate');
fDate1.startup();
```

If I use the browser UI to set the value to 1 September 2015, it displays as "01/09/2015", and there's a hidden `input` element with the value "2015-09-01", as expected.

I want to get the exact value of that hidden `input` element.

I've used the following code for testing:

```
var date1=fDate1.get('value');
console.log('date1='+date1);
```

And the console output is:
`date1=Tue Sep 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)`
This is not what I need, and not what I'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `fDate1.valueNode.value`. fDate1 is the DateTextBox Object which contains this hidden DOM Node(fDate1.valueNode). If you get the value of that hidden DOM Node you can have the string value you see in the DateTextBox.

Comment: Marked this as the answer, since you posted first and took the time to revise after it was deleted by a review. I doubt I'd have worked it out otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the easiest way to get the date value in the desired format:

```
var date1=fDate1.valueNode.value;
```

It works, though I couldn't find any mention of `valueNode` in the Dojo documentation for `dijit/form/DateTextBox`.

Someone else posted this solution as either an answer or a comment to my question several hours ago, but that seems to have since been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The value you receive via `get('value')` is actually a full-blown Date object, which should effectively enable you to get whatever format you want, in various ways.  For example:

```
var date1 = fDate1.get('value');
// stamp = dojo/date/stamp
console.log(stamp.toISOString(date1).slice(0, 10));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found a simpler solution, which I've put in an answer to my own question.